# How do I enable hotkeys to be displayed?

Tags: interface

Here's a screen cap from a video of what I'm talking about. I would really like to have this enabled to make it easier to remember keybinds. My blender doesn't have the keybinds displayed alongside the gizmos/modifiers/etc, so I'm often just googling things I forget.

[image: Tips]

Comment: Hello and welcome, by default, you should have that activated, if not, make a factory reset. Another thing is that it's only displayed when you use Left click as your default mouse click (not 100% sure, but i think)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the Tooltips under User Preferences > Interface:

[image: Tool]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! When I have this enabled it only tells me what the gizmo does, not what key its bound to. I already had tool tips enabled too. Is there some add on I need that gives the tool tips more info, like what key the action is bound to?

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. As far as I know, the tooltips are the only control for it.  You may have to try as Emir suggested and do a factory reset.